# How to use logical not operator in complex conditional expression in Bash?

Tags: bash, conditional-statements, logical-operators

I would like to have the logical not for the following condition expression in bash,
how can I do this?

```
if [[ $var==2 || $var==30 || $var==50 ]] ; then
  do something
fi
```

how can I prepend the logical not directly in the above expression, it's very tedious to change it again into things like this:

```
if [[ $var!=2 && $var!=30 && $var==50 ]] ; then
  do something
fi
```

thanks for any hints!

Answer (score 49, accepted):

```
if ! [[ $var == 2 || $var == 30 || $var == 50 ]] ; then
  do something
fi
```

Or:

```
if [[ ! ($var == 2 || $var == 30 || $var == 50) ]] ; then
  do something
fi
```

And a good practice is to have spaces between your conditional operators and operands.

Some could also suggest that if you're just comparing numbers, use an arithmetic operator instead, or just use `(( ))`:

```
if ! [[ var -eq 2 || var -eq 30 || var -eq 50 ]] ; then
  do something
fi

if ! (( var == 2 || var == 30 || var == 50 )) ; then
  do something
fi
```

Although it's not commendable or caution is to be given if `$var` could sometimes be not numeric or has no value or unset, since it could mean 0 as default or another value of another variable if it's a name of a variable.